# PHP check string has contains only letters numbers and spaces in any language

Tags: php, preg-match, special-characters

How can i check string has contains only letters numbers and spaces in any language?

I have tried bellow but it's not checks special characters like -*/.

```
 preg_match("/[\p{L}]/u", $string )
 preg_match("/[\p{N}]/u", $string  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
preg_match('~^[\p{L}\p{N}\s]+$~uD', $string)
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[\p{L}\p{N}\s]+` - one or more letters, digits or whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

The `u` modifier will enable Unicode string parsing and also make all patterns in the regex Unicode aware, and `D` will make `$` match the *very end* of the string.

Comment: ~ see https://stackoverflow.com/a/938113/251674

Comment: @ManuelAlves These are called "*regex delimiters*", see [PHP documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).